# Is there an intuitive explanation to the fact that the solutions to the time-independent Schrödinger equation form a complete basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, schroedinger-equation, hilbert-space

We were always told that the solutions to the time-independent Schrödinger equation form a complete eigenbasis for the space of all functions (**all** functions?) but I never understood why this is the case. Is there a logical explanation or is it just a weird coincidence?

Comment: Do you want an intuitive or logical explanation? I don't think there is a simple intuitive explanation, but it can easily (depending on the level of rigour one expects) be explained by operator theory.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68822/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "time-independent Schrödinger equation" is just an equation for the *eigenvalues* and *eigenvectors* of the Hamiltonian operator on the Hilbert space of states (typically $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathrm{d}x)$, the "space of wavefunctions")

The [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) tells us that the eigenvectors of *any* self-adjoint operator form a basis for the space the operator lives on, so as long as your Hamiltonian is self-adjoint, this will hold. (Care has to be taken - Hamiltonians used in physics might only be *essentially self-adjoint*, or merely Hermitian)

So there is nothing special about the "time-independent Schrödinger equation" - the eigenvectors of *other self-adjoint observables* also form such bases. No "intuiton" exists for this because it's just a general consequence of the fact/axiom that quantum mechanical observables typically are self-adjoint. You might also pick self-adjoint operators that don't model any physical observable, and you still get this.

Comment: "Essentially self-adjoint" means they have a unique self-adjoint extension.

Answer (score 2):

It is a mathematical theorem that self-adjoint operators in Hilbert space have a complete spectrum.

Note that "self-adjoint" has a special mathematical meaning. Not every Hermitian symmetric operator is self-adjoint. For example, the 1D free Schrodinger Hamiltonian on an open interval without boundary conditions is not self-adjoint. The reason is that we can choose periodic boundary conditions with different phase shifts. Different choices define different self-adjoint operators with different eigenfunctions and eigenvalues. Some potentials do not define self-adjoint Schrodinger Hamiltonians. It can be difficult to prove whether a given potential does so.