# Why is the "expansion postulate" a postulate of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm currently reading the following set of [lecture notes on quantum chemistry](http://www.chem.yale.edu/~batista/classes/vvv/v570.pdf), which includes the so-called "expansion postulate" as a fundamental postulate of quantum mechanics: "The eigenfunctions of a linear and hermitian operator form a complete basis set."

How is this a postulate of quantum mechanics, rather than a provable mathematical property of linear hermitian operators? Isn't the expansion postulate just a consequence of the spectral theorem for an infinite-dimensional Hilbert Space?

If the eigenfunctions of a linear, hermitian operator forming an orthogonal basis is not a mathematically provable fact about wavefunctions, wouldn't that necessarily imply that there exist hermitian, linear operators on wavefunctions whose eigenfunctions do not form an orthogonal basis?

Comment: Perhaps these notes are written for an audience that is not expected to understand functional analysis (like the spectral theorem): In such a situation, it may be better to simply say "we postulate"...

Comment: It's just the spectral theorem, although care must be taken since it holds only for *self-adjoint*, not merely Hermitian operators (there is a difference on infinite-dimensional spaces). This question is basically unanswerable since the premise that the "expansion postulate" is a postulate is just false.

Comment: I never heard of this didactic strategy before. It seems to be a way of declaring "we won't be looking at cases where this isn't true".  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68822/proof-for-the-completeness-of-eigenfunctions-of-a-self-adjoint-operator

Answer (score 2):

It's a postulate, not because it's a self-consistent mathematical property, but rather because it is an assumption about how the physical world may, or may not, be described.

There are many many different types of linear vector spaces other than a Hilbert space, so to make things easy they make an assumption and run with it until proven otherwise.

Comment: Your argument doesn't seem consistent to me. A position vector in classical mechanics can be written as a linear combination of any set of orthogonal basis vectors, but this isn't a postulate of classical mechanics and it would be ludicrous to make it one. Further, the statement of the expansion postulate is entirely mathematical in nature: it claims that the eigenfunctions of _any_ linear, hermitian operator form a basis, not just operators which correspond to an observable.

Comment: "The eigenfunctions of a linear and hermitian operator form a complete basis set."  Just because the rules of mathematics allows for a linear hermitian operator to form a complete basis set, doesn't mean that the rules of nature do.  Hence, it's an assumption about the relationship between the math rules and the observable.

Comment: This is wrong. This is not axiomatic; it can be proven mathematically. Your distinction between the rules of mathematics and nature is completely irrelevant. Physical correspondence is based on the assumption of (a) some quantum-mechanical axioms, which are not the "expansion postulate", and (b) some mathematical and meta-logical axioms, from which all QM follows, like the OP's question. Following your argument, all QM statements should therefore be "postulates" or "assumptions", as one cannot positively prove them. Science follows falsifiability.

Comment: @juanrocamonde your comment doesn’t make sense.  The proof of connection between a mathematical framework and physics is an experiment.  Moreover only an experiment can falsify a theory.  The original post concerns itself with a certain mathematical property. It’s easy to think of examples from physics where this property wouldn’t be applicable.

Comment: The completeness "postulate" is not a postulate or an assumption. The assumptions are the axioms, and that is not one of them. Experiments test the applicability of the axioms.

Comment: Mathematical axioms produce mathematical results. QM axioms link these results to our physical world. You are conflating the two. Surely there are "some assumptions" from QM that make results falsifiable. If you can provide a source where a tested formulation of QM uses the expansion postulate as an axiom, please do. In the meantime, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac-von_Neumann_axioms

Comment: I understand this level of formalism might not be familiar to some physicists, especially if their education / research has a strong experimental focus; they just accept that some stuff in QM "works until proven false" and that it "produces the right numbers in the lab". This is suitable for designing and executing experiments, but it breaks down when you attempt to explain the mathematical foundations of QM. Theorems in QM - as for physics in general - are not assumptions, but derived from first principles.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem